# running multiple instances of a single MPI executable in parallel on a cluster using mpirun options?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I'm trying to write a shell script to perform some kind of algorithm, and a part of it requires parallel execution of an MPI executable across multiple input files on a grid engine cluster. From what I read, it seems like `mpirun` supports MPMD execution by using the colon sign or using the application context/schema file and then perform `mpirun --app my_appfile`. And below is what my `my_appfile` looks like,

```
-np 12 /path/to/executable /path/to/dir1/input1
-np 12 /path/to/executable /path/to/dir2/input2
-np 12 /path/to/executable /path/to/dir3/input3
...
-np 12 /path/to/executable /path/to/dir10/input10
```

I was trying to parallely execute 10 instances of the same executable and assign the resources in the cluster accordingly (120 processes in this case in SGE's orte parallel environment).

However, there was a problem. Each input file was written to generate an output in the same directory as each particular input file. As I submitted the job (the submission script contains only the `mpirun --app my_appfile` line), it shows only the output from input1 in dir1, but not the rest. So I wonder what is the problem here. Is it the problem with mpirun options or the problem with how the cluster does the job? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We will need for information to try and help: 1) what is status of jobs i.e. output from qstat -j <jobid>? 2) Does this also fail if you request fewer cores? 3) Try and launch 2 instances only. Does that work? 4) What are general specs of the cluster? Basically, try and gather as much information as possible, and post it here.  Good that you asked specific question, but whenever asking something on SO, you need to provide as much information as possible and show that you have tried many different avenues, which helps us figure out the problem.

Comment: Hi @Vince, I really appreciate all your helps. I tried a lot of workarounds tweaking the SGE side of things but all the methods I tried didn't really work as I expected, but I found the way to wrap things into one submission script. So, I wrote a python script to extract `$PE_HOSTFILE` and write into 10 smaller MPI **nodefiles**, and then use the shell's `for` loop to submit each instance of `mpirun` with the corresponding **nodefile** in background, and it works!

Anyway, thank you so much for everything! I learned so much more about SGE! StackOverflow is indeed a great community! :)

Comment: Good to hear it worked out:) if you have the time, submit your solution as an answer to this question. It will surely help someone in the future.